# Get selected values from js tree without disabled

Tags: javascript, arrays, jstree, selected, disabled-input

I have js tree and some nodes are disabled. I want to get selected node values without `disabled` nodes.

[image]

I used the following code to get selected node values, but it includes disabled values too

```
$(document).on('click', '#users_perm_save', function (event) {
       var result = $('#jstree').jstree('get_selected'); 
    });
```

What will be the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Array filter method for that. Here is what you can do.

First get all the selected nodes and then filter it which is not disabled.

```
$(document).on('click', '#users_perm_save', function (event) {
   var result = $('#jstree').jstree('get_selected',true); 
  var checkedNodes = result.filter((node)=>{
    return node.state.disabled==false
  }).map((checked)=>{
    return checked.id
  });
   console.log(checkedNodes);
});
```

Comment: result shows full node can I get the values/id only ?